# i want to make server to cut out additional request when processing first request

Tags: multithreading, fastapi

here is my code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

import threading
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

@app.middleware('http')
async def check(file: dict, next):
    if lock.acquire(timeout=0.001):
        response = await next(file)
        lock.release()
    else:
        print('bad')
        response = JSONResponse(content='bad')
    
    return response

@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(file: dict):
    print(file)

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
    return file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = threading.Lock()
    
    uvicorn.run(app, host='', port=1024)
```

i want to make server to cut out additional request when processing first request.
but log 'bad' never happened(i used client that send 10 requests simultaneously)
what should i do? and what should i learn? in fastapi asynchronization is so hard.

i expected server to accept 1 and reject 9 but it respond 10 synchronously